# Prevent event from being fired when calling expandItem()

Tags: events, tree, vaadin

the title says almost everything. When I execute the expandItem() function programmatically I do not want the fired event causing a nodeExpand() call.

I have implemented the ExpandListener:

```
@Override
public void nodeExpand(ExpandEvent event)
{
    System.out.println("This should only appear when the user clicks the node on the UI");
}
```

When I call the expandItem() function of the Tree class, there is always an event fired. This is the code of the original Tree class:

```
public boolean expandItem(Object itemId) {
    boolean success = expandItem(itemId, true);
    requestRepaint();
    return success;
}

private boolean expandItem(Object itemId, boolean sendChildTree) {

    // Succeeds if the node is already expanded
    if (isExpanded(itemId)) {
        return true;
    }

    // Nodes that can not have children are not expandable
    if (!areChildrenAllowed(itemId)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Expands
    expanded.add(itemId);

    expandedItemId = itemId;
    if (initialPaint) {
        requestRepaint();
    } else if (sendChildTree) {
        requestPartialRepaint();
    }
    fireExpandEvent(itemId);

    return true;
}
```

What I did now to get this work is:

```
m_Tree.removeListener((ExpandListener)this);
m_Tree.expandItem(sItemId);
m_Tree.addListener((ExpandListener)this);
```

Is there any nicer approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to create a switch to your listener. For example:

```
private boolean listenerDisabled;

void setListenerDisabled(boolean disabled) 
{
    listenerDisabled = disabled;
}

@Override
public void nodeExpand(ExpandEvent event)
{
    if(listenerDisabled) return;
    System.out.println("This should only appear when the user clicks the node on the UI");
}
```

and disable the listener when needed.

If there are more than one listener, you could try creating a subclass of Tree and overriding some methods.

Comment: I had something like this before. I'm wondering if this is really performant, because everytime you call the expandItem() method programmatically, a event is fired and caught by the listener. But this does not mean that my solution is faster. ;)

Comment: After waiting for about a month, I guess there is no better solution for this than yours or my approach. So i think it's fair to say that you earn the best answer.